# Cannot import name 'login' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am currently working on a project in Django... I am trying to import `login` from `django.contrib.auth.views` but I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'login'
```

Here is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.home),
    url('login', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'})
]
```

error message(cmd):

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'login'
```

Comment: The Django docs show that import was only available in 1.8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The old function-based authentication views, including `login`, [were removed in Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-2-1). In Django 1.11+ you should switch to the new class-based authentication views, including [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView).

I suggest you also switch to use the new `path()` instead of `url()`.

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html')),
]
```

If you want to stick with `url()` or `re_path()`, then make sure you use `^` and `$` to begin and end your regexes:

```
url(r'^$', views.home),
url(r'^login$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html')))
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. I didn't put the (r'^)  because I didn't think I needed it in Django 2, but will be using it from now on. Thanks for the code.(Apologies for the following question I accidentally submitted the comment when I was working it out lol). Thanks again!

Comment: In Django 2.0+, the simplest approach is to switch to `path()` then you don't need `^$`. You still need them with `url()`, since it behaves the same as in earlier versions of Django and still uses regexes.

Comment: @JShen if this answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as "accepted answer"